# Read access out of stm8 address range error in st8s013f2 controller

Tags: assembly, microcontroller, memory-mapping, stm8

I am using stm8s103f2p controller in simulator mode in ST visual studio (assembly language), and during compiling my one sample file, i am getting error "read access out of stm8 address range".

Map file:
BYTES           ; The following addresses are 8 bits long
    segment byte at 0-ff 'ram0'

```
WORDS           ; The following addresses are 16 bits long
segment byte at 100-1ff 'ram1'

WORDS           ; The following addresses are 16 bits long
segment byte at 200-3ff 'stack'

WORDS           ; The following addresses are 16 bits long
segment byte at 4000-427F 'eeprom'

WORDS           ; The following addresses are 16 bits long
segment byte at 8080-8FFF 'rom'

WORDS           ; The following addresses are 16 bits long
segment byte at 8000-807F 'vectit'
```

source file:
stm8/

```
#include "mapping.inc"

 segment 'rom'
```

.main:
    ; sample code
    CPL A

```
end
```

Comment: what is you simulator definition?

Comment: I not got the exact question, but I want to clarify "In ST visual studio, in the debugger mode there is option of simulator (i currently do not have debugger to debug the circuit), that i am using to checking my code. My st visual studio version 4.3.12